# Proving conservation of heat for the Heat Equation by direct integration

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, heat-equation

> For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, let $u(x,t) = (\Gamma_{D} (\cdot , t ) \ast g)(x)$ with $g(x) \ge 0,$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(x) dx < \infty$. Prove that for all $t>0$,
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx,$$
> the meaning of this statement is that the total heat is conserved.
> Using the formula for $u(x,t)$, show by direct integration that for all $t > 0$,
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \ dx.$$
> **Hint:** Because $g(x) \ge 0$, and $\Gamma_{D} (x,t) \ge 0$ , you may always exchange the order of iterated integrals

#### Attempt at solution

Since by proprety
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Gamma(x,t) \ dx =1,$$
then it follows by change of variable that
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Gamma(x-y,t) \ dx =1$$
as well. So then,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) \ dx &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(x-y,t)g(y) \ dy \ dx  \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Gamma(x-y,t) \ dx \ dy \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y) \ dy
\end{align}
Since $y$ is a dummy variable this is equivalent to
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(x,t) \ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) \ dx.$$

I'm not sure if my proof holds, particularly I'm not sure if what I just provided falls into the category of "direct integration".

Comment: That's correct, though you of course didn't prove the interchange is justified explicitly, you just took it as given. In this case you could've given Tonelli's theorem as a straightforward justification.

Comment: That is an interesting addition thank you.